# Why is Google Colab taking so long for learning these simple neural networks?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run the followin code on google colab:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

sns.set()

(train_data,train_targets),(test_data,test_targets)=boston_housing.load_data()

mean=np.mean(train_data)
std=np.std(train_data)

train_data_norm=(train_data-mean)/std
test_data_norm=(test_data-mean)/std

def build_model():
    model=models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation="relu",
                          input_shape=(train_data_norm.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss="mse",metrics=["mae"])
    return model 


model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,epochs=30,verbose=0)
param_grid = {"epochs":range(1,11)}

kf1=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None, shuffle=False) #n_splits = number of folds
kf2=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5,test_size=0.20,random_state=1)

grid_model_KFFalse=GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv=kf1,n_jobs=-1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_model_KFTrue=GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv=kf2,n_jobs=-1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_model_SS=GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,cv=ss,n_jobs=-1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

listKFFalse=[]
listKFTrue=[]
listSS=[]

for i in range(1,21):
  grid_model_KFFalse.fit(train_data, train_targets)
  grid_model_KFTrue.fit(train_data, train_targets)
  grid_model_SS.fit(train_data, train_targets)
  mseKFFalse=mean_squared_error(grid_model_KFFalse.predict(test_data),test_targets)
  mseKFTrue=mean_squared_error(grid_model_KFTrue.predict(test_data),test_targets)
  mseSS=mean_squared_error(grid_model_SS.predict(test_data),test_targets)
  listKFFalse=np.append(listKFFalse,[mseKFFalse])
  listKFTrue=np.append(listKFTrue,[mseKFTrue])
  listSS=np.append(listSS,[mseSS])
```

You can check it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P-HNBtMNDqUBsoUaBL9BlPgrQ5al3QrO?usp=sharing).

I've done on my laptop 1 run on a jupyter notebook, instead of the 21, and the part where it's slowest is in the 'for' block, but that's to be expected.

The code compiles without error, since I've already managed to run it for 5 cycles/simulations without problems.

However, it's taking a very long time... I wonder why it is. Isn't google colab supposed to use GPU(or TPU) when learning neural networks with keras? I've already changed the Runtime type to GPU or TPU, and it's still very slow.

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

> **Seems too good to be true. What are the limitations?**

> Colab resources are not guaranteed and not unlimited, and the usage limits sometimes
> fluctuate. This is necessary for Colab to be able to provide resources
> for free. For more details, see [Resource Limits](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding TPU usage, if you refer to [TPUs in Colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=FpvUOuC3j27n) you'll see some code snippets for connecting to a TPU:

```
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver() 
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
```

In the snippet/colab provided, the TPU isn't being used which is why you see no difference in performance. You would need to migrate from base `keras` to `tf.keras` and use distribution strategies if you want to use TPUs.